# How to access module controller action

Tags: php, url, yii, module, redirect

I have created a module(**education**) using Gii. This module have one controller(**article**) with three actions(**index, read, write**) in it.

I access module something like this:

> http://example.com/index.php/education/article/index *(working fine)*
>
> http://example.com/index.php/education/article/read  *(redirecting to
>   index action)*
>
> http://example.com/index.php/education/article/write *(redirecting to
>   index action)*

So problem is that I can access only **index** action in **article** controller. When I try to access any other action, it always redirect to **index** action.

I have following entries in config/main:

```
'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'password',
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        ),
        'education'

    ),
```

Any idea what is the problem ?

Comment: please check accessRules for article

Comment: no access rules are implemented in article controller.

Comment: Show us your code : read or write action, and url config

Answer (score 0):

May be problem in **access filters**. You are trying to open some action, but you have no rights and controller redirects you to **default** action

Answer (score 0):

This topic really helpful for me. Before I found this topic. I have the same error like this. It's always redirect to index action. Especially, this happen when I create module based login, I have no idea about this. After I read Pavel hint, I check the main.php again and find out that I tested a **rules** and forgot to delete this. 
This is the line in urlManager rules.

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/*'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```